# Is it possible to track the entire string entered in text field in any app through custom keyboard app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am making a custom keyboard app. I am trying to track what the user types through that keyboard in any app. I think we cannot receive the entire string the user typed at once(If it is possible, somebody please explain me) I am tracking it character by character and adding it to a string. But here the problem is if the user types some text like "abde" and places the cursor in the middle to enter some character like 'c', Since I am receving character by character, my string would be "abdec" but the actual string would be "abcde". Could somebody please help me how to resolve this? Is it possible to track the position of cursor or is there any way so that entire string can be received at once when the user clicks enter or submit?

Comment: android studio is an IDE. it helps you to code your apps, but your question doesn't have anything to do with the IDE except for the fact that you're _using_ it to make your app. so i've removed it, please only add the tag if you're asking about the IDE specifically :)

Comment: As its a `Keyboard`, you could get a proper String when the user hits the "Enter, Search, Done, Send" or whatever the actual action is.

Comment: I know how to receive the text entered in the text field (using EditText and findbyId) which is created by me. But if the user types in some other app, is it possible to receive in the same way using findbyId? or Please suggest to me if is there any way